# Vuetify Preview image with avatar icon

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Is it possible to do Preview image with avatar  before upload using Vuetify.I was searching for that a lot.If yes please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this answer to your question but

```html
 <v-avatar size="120">
  <v-img
    :src="'URL FULL SIZE IMAGE'"
    :lazy-src="'URL BEFORE LOADING (OR PREVIEW) '"
    @error="'URL ON ERROR'"
  >
  <!-- ALSO, YOU CAN USE A LOADING ANIMATION -->
    <template v-slot:placeholder>  
      <v-progress-circular
        style="margin-top:40px"
        indeterminate
        color="custm_theme_6"
      ></v-progress-circular> 
    </template>
  </v-img>
</v-avatar>
```